# how to get related model data in View model - One to Many Relation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I know this is asked question but I confused what's the best practice to get data from a related model in View Model.

I want to show the review or comment data in view with category Name but in View Model CategoryId is just exist.

My question is should I add list of categories in Vm and find intended category by categoryId in View or there is better and optimized solution for this situation.

Review Model :

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public bool IsBuyer { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment Model :

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(500)]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Category Model :

```
public class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Review { get; set; }
}
```

Vm :

```
public class RevComVm
{
    public Review Review { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }

    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/multiple-models-in-a-single-view-in-asp-net-mvc/) help you?

Comment: @Chen Unfortunately no, because there isn't any relation between two models in this artices. My question is how to get some data of related model in view

Comment: The data you get in the view depends on the data you pass to it in the controller, you can't get data from other models directly in the view. You can process all the data in the controller and pass it into the view, or pass the ID from the view into the controller to get data from other models. @Pablo

Comment: @Chen finally I did this solution and pass list of categories to the view in controller. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I added List of categories to View Model to access review/comment category and find specific record by CategoryId that saved in model using linq.

```
public class RevComVm
{
    public Review Review { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }

    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories {get; set;}
}
```